# How can one find an orthogonal frame $X_1, X_2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If we consider $\phi : \mathbb{R^2} → \mathbb{R^3}$ defined by $\phi(x, y) = (x, y,sin(x + y))$

How can one find an orhogonal frame $X_1, X_2 : \mathbb{R^2} → \mathbb{R^2}$ with respect to the Riemannian metric g and in addition how can I write down the volume 2-form on corresponding to your frame $X_1, X_2$?

With $g_{i,j} (p) = g(p)(e_i, e_j )$ where $g = \phi∗g_E$ is the pull-back of the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R^3}$

First, I proved that the jacobian $J_\phi(p)$ has no kernel for all $p \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and then I was able to show that this defines a Riemann metric on $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the following computations.

$\phi*g_{11} = 1 + cos^2(x+y)$, $\phi*g_{12}=\phi*g_{21} = cos^2(x+y)$ and $\phi*g_{22} = 1 + cos^2(x+y)$

From here I am stuck on how to proceed. Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $g$? It's not very clear the problem, can you rephrase it better?

Comment: I will change it immediately.

Comment: Find any frame of tangent vectors along the surface. Use Gram-Schmidt for the frame at each point to solve for an orthonormal frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your vector fields take the form $X=X^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+X^2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, $Y=Y^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+Y^2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ for some functions $X^i:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y^i:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$. Then, in coordinates you have $$g(X,Y)=g_{11}X^1Y^1+g_{12}X^1Y^2+g_{22}X^2Y^2+g_{21}X^2Y^1=0$$ You can solve this functional equation for $X^i$ and $Y^i$.

In order to get a volume form, you can compute the musical isomorphism on these vector fields, namely, let $\alpha=g(X,\cdot)$ and $\beta=g(Y,\cdot)$. Since $X,Y$ are linearly independent, $dA=\alpha\wedge\beta$ will give you a non-vanishing two-form on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

**Edit: Here's a little more info:**

If we plug in our coefficients, we get $$(1+\cos^2(x+y))X^1Y^1+\cos^2(x+y)(X^2Y^1+Y^2X^1)+(1+\cos^2(x+y))X^2Y^2=0$$
We first can make an arbitrary choice for $X$, we'll just take the constant coordinate vector field $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, hence $X^1=1,X^2=0$. This simplifies our equation to $$(1+\cos^2(x+y))Y^1+\cos^2(x+y)Y^2=0$$ From here, you can get a relation between $Y^1$ and $Y^2$, and then by assuming some form of $Y^1$ you can get $Y^2$ using said relation.

Comment: Thankyou, I am not quite sure how I have to solve the functional equation.